# Change row style when expand on Kendo UI Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an angular 5 application with the library Kendo UI. In this application I try to add some styles to a Kendo UI grid. 
So, I want to change the style of a row when the user expand this row to see the details.

In my grid I have

```
<kendo-grid
#grid
[kendoGridBinding]="getDataService().listOfSolution"
[resizable]="false"
[pageSize]="10"
[pageable]="true"
[sortable]="true"
[filterable]="false"
[groupable]="false"
[reorderable]="false"
[selectable]="false"
[scrollable]="'none'"
[rowClass]="rowCallback"
(detailCollapse)="test($event)"
(detailExpand)="test($event)"
style="border: none;">
....
</kendo-grid>
```

So I get an event when the row is expanded or collapsed but I don't know how to change the style of this row.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: at that event you have to assign class Or set css property by DOM read

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to keep track of the expanded rows via the `detailCollapse` and `detailExpand` events (either by `index` or some kind of `id`).

Once you are tracking the currently expanded rows, utilize the `rowClass` input to add a new css-class if the current row/dataItem is expanded.

**Example:** ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjgKQmrXcYp3tpDryD9z?p=preview))

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    expandedRows = [];

    onExpand(event) {
        // add index/id to this.expandedRows
    }

    onCollapse(event) {
        // remove index/id from this.expandedRows
    }

    rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs) {
        // if index/id from context is in this.expandedRows
        // return a custom css-class
    }
}
```